# Cargo plugin for Gradle ignoring configured port

Tags: jboss, gradle, cargo

I have the following configuration :

```
cargo {
    containerId = deployContainerId
    port = jbossManagementPort

    deployable {
        file = tasks.getByPath(':frontend:war').archivePath
        context = 'xxxxxx'
    }

    remote {
        hostname = 'localhost'
        username = 'xxxxxxx'
        password = 'xxxxxxx'
    }

    local {
        homeDir = file(jbossHome)
        timeout = 60000
    }
}
```

When I invoke **Gradle** with

```
gradle -PjbossManagementPort=12345 -PdeployContainerId=jboss7x -PjbossHome=/opt/jboss cargoRedeployRemote
```

The configured port is ignored. It still tries to connect to 9999. I have tried variants, such as

```
gradle -Pcargo.port=12345 -PdeployContainerId=jboss7x -PjbossHome=/opt/jboss cargoRedeployRemote
```

And

```
gradle -Pcargo.jboss.management-native.port=12345 -PdeployContainerId=jboss7x -PjbossHome=/opt/jboss cargoRedeployRemote
```

But neither has any effect.

How do I tell Cargo to use a different port than the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use -D for the cargo-property rather than -P:

```
gradle -Dcargo.jboss.management-native.port=12345 -PdeployContainerId=jboss7x -PjbossHome=/opt/jboss cargoRedeployRemote
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that you can define in your gradle build to handle this issue.

```
remote {
            //You can define custom cargo properties here
            containerProperties {
                property 'cargo.jboss.management-native.port', 12345
            }
            hostname = 'localhost'
            username = 'xxxxxxx'
            password = 'xxxxxxx'
        }
```